# App deployed to Cloud Foundry fails to start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cloud-foundry

I've tried to deploy my Node.js application to Bluemix but it fails.

When I run `cf logs IssueTracker --recent` I see this error:

```
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR module.js:549
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     throw err;
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     ^
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:6915)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at r (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:186)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:11679)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:12243)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at r (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:186)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:71669)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:73288)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at r (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:186)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:73356)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at r (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:186)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:73750)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.38+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at r (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:186)
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! errno 1
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! issue-tracker-pc@1.0.0 start: `NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js`
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! 
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Failed at the issue-tracker-pc@1.0.0 start script.
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.43+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.45+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   2018-12-10T16:50:24.45+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/.npm/_logs/2018-12-10T16_50_24_438Z-debug.log
```

I'm new to Cloud Foundry so not sure what to do next. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a missing dependency in your app: `Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'`.

The command being run by CF to start your app is `NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js`. Try running locally to see if you can reproduce.

You might also want to try running on a clean VM to rule out the case where the missing dependency is installed globally on your developer workstation. Globally installed dependencies won't be available when your app runs on CF. The only thing available is what's installed by NPM/Yarn based on your package.json file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works on my local machine. I'll try a clean VM to rule out the possibility of a global dependency.

Comment: When I initially tried to deploy my app it failed with the error `failed: The app upload is invalid: Invalid zip archive.` After some research I found that it was because node_modules was present. I deleted the folder and did another push. This time it seemed to deploy but won't start due to missing dependencies. How do I get them to install?

Comment: Check your `package.json` and make sure everything necessary to run your app is in that file. The node.js buildpack will run `npm` and install all the dependencies in that file.

Comment: When I put the following into my dependencies it worked:

`webpack@4.6.0
 webpack-dev-middleware@3.1.3
 webpack-hot-middleware@2.22.1`

I already had these listed in `devDependencies`.

Comment: I don't believe dev dependencies are installed because they would typically only be used for development. The buildpack enables `production` -> https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production

Answer (score 0):

In my case package.json has wrong entry.
Please cross verify

Comment: Which entry was wrong? Why do you think your case is the same as the one in the question?

Comment: It was pointing to server.js instead of index.js for start-up, which causing failure to start. So similarly, the webpack module is not context, So Verify the package.json for the dependencies.